# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I recieve an error when building my vs2008 .net 3.5 solution 
Error   1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'

```
String _XSLTPath = Page.Request.Url.Scheme 
    + "://" 
    + Page.Request.Url.Authority 
    + Page.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') 
    + '/' 
    + "webparts/weatherandtime/weather/xslt/RSSWeatherXSL.xsl";
```

The Page object seems to be higlighting in green which is not what i want. Can someone explain whats going on?

Thanks,

Comment: The extra parenthesis has been removed but still causes the error. It seems odd I can get a instance of the object just a couple of lines down in the code without instantiating before?

Comment: Can you qualify Page with this? this.Page.Request...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access the non-static property `Page.Request` without an instance. You have to call it on an instance. Something like `myPage.Request`.

Comment: @Daniel This looks like code that lives in a control. A control has the this.Page property...so this code should be valid. I think his issue is the extra parenthesis at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a StringBuilder to make this a little more managable:

```
using System.Text;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// if this is a control or WebPart, replace Request with this.Page.Request
sb.Append(Request.Url.Scheme);
sb.Append("://");
sb.Append(Request.Url.Authority);
sb.Append(Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
sb.Append("/");
sb.Append("webparts/weatherandtime/weather/xslt/RSSWeatherXSL.xsl");

String _XSLTPath = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Page.Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context.aspx) instead:

```
String _XSLTPath2 = Context.Request.Url.Scheme
                    + "://"
                    + Context.Request.Url.Authority
                    + Context.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/')
                    + '/'
                    + "webparts/weatherandtime/weather/xslt/RSSWeatherXSL.xsl";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the Page property for a control from a method or property that's defined as `static`?

It's hard to see exactly what's going on without seeing the full context of the code, but that would explain why you're seeing the problem in one part of the code but not in another.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a right approach:

```
String _XSLTPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;
```