# Why am I getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Photrax.App.DBPath.get'"?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, app.xaml

Leveraging the code [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx), I added this to App.xaml.cs:

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    public string DBPath { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        . . .
        this.DBPath = Path.Combine(
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "photrax.sqlite");
        . . .
```

...but this code:

```
internal static List<PhotraxBaseData> SavePhotoset(List<PhotraxExifData> exifData)
{
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(App.DBPath))
    . . .
```

...fails with, "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Photrax.App.DBPath.get'*"

Photrax is my project's namespace; but what's up with the appended "get" jazz?

What do I need to do to supply the supposedly global db path to the SQLiteConnection constructor?

Comment: Do try to search for error messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051558/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBPath` is a non-static property of `App`.  In order to access it, you need an instance of `App`.  You are attempting to access it like a static property.

If the path to the DB does not change in your application (e.g. you do not have multiple databases, each referenced by a different instance of `App`, you could consider making that property static.

Comment: Okay; I was thinking "App" would be something that was "always around." Yeah, I made it static.